# Why are CSS styles missing when inserting a layout, saved row, or saved column using Beaver Builder?

Tags: wordpress

When using the [`fl_builder_insert_layout`](https://docs.wpbeaverbuilder.com/beaver-builder/advanced-builder-techniques/shortcodes/shortcode-reference/#beaver-builder-shortcode-syntax-fl_builder_insert_layout) shortcode or inserting a saved row or column through a module (such as a modal popup), the content that's inserted is missing CSS styles and appears as plain text. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Load CSS and JavaScript inline by using [this snippet](https://docs.wpbeaverbuilder.com/beaver-builder/developer/how-to-tips/load-css-and-javascript-inline/):

```php
add_filter( 'fl_builder_render_assets_inline', '__return_true' );
```

If you're not using a child theme, you can add the snippet using the [Code Snippets](https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/) plugin.